# How to copy mongo data that's stored in a remote server to my local docker container?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to mongo and I have a web app the uses mongo to store data. I can get the app to run the docker compose but data gets left out of it when I do. The mongo data is in a remote host and I need to copy all of that data and store it into the mongo container so that dockerized app runs with the same data

I've attempted to dump the data from the remote host on to the container, based on some code I found while researching for this.

```
# Backup DB
docker run \
 --rm \
 --link running_mongo:mongo \
 -v /data/mongo/backup:/backup \
 mongo \
 bash -c ‘mongodump --out /backup --host 10.22.150.7:27017’
 # Download the dump
scp -r jsikala@10.22.150.7:/data/mongo/backup ./backup
```

The result I got from doing that is

```
[jsikala@koala-jsikala koala]$ docker run  --rm  --link running_mongo:3.2.0  -v /data/mongo/backup:/backup  mongo  bash -c ‘mongodump --out /backup --host 10.22.150.7:27017’
Unable to find image 'mongo:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/mongo
Digest: sha256:93c98ffc714faa1fa501297d35670a62835dbb7e62243cee0c491433ea523f30
Status: Image is up to date for mongo:latest
docker: Error response from daemon: could not get container for running_mongo: No such container: running_mongo.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I'm assume I did something trivial wrong.

This is my docker-compose file for a bit of context on what is suppose to happen

```
version: "3"
volumes:
    data:
        external:
            name: ${MONGO_VOLUME_NAME}
services:
    rails:
        image: rails2
        container_name: koala_rails_${USER}
        environment: 
            - KOALA_ENV
            - RAILS_PORT
            - KOALA_INGEST_URL=${INGEST_PROTOCOL}://ingest:${INGEST_PORT}
            - KOALA_MONGO_URL=mongo_service:27017
            - KOALA_REDIS_URL=redis_service:6379
            - KOALA_PKI_IN_DEV
            - KOALA_USER_ID_HEADER
            - USER
            - USERNAME
            - KOALA_REGISTER_USER_URL
            - KOALA_SECURITY_VALIDATOR_URL
            - CERT_FILE_PEM=/usr/src/app/certs/public.pem
            - PRIVATE_CERT_FILE_PEM=/usr/src/app/certs/private-key.pem
            - SSL_CA_FILE=/usr/src/app/certs/ca.pem
            - LOGNAME
            - KOALA_SECRET_KEY_BASE
            - KOALA_MONGO_USERNAME
            - KOALA_MONGO_PASSWORD
            - KOALA_HELP_URL
            - KOALA_CONTACT_EMAIL
            - KOALA_USE_CERTS
            - BUNDLE_GEMFILE
            - KOALA_SERVER_URL
            - RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES
            - RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT
        ports:
            - "${RAILS_PORT}:${RAILS_PORT}"
        volumes:
            - ${CERT_FILE_PEM}:/usr/src/app/certs/public.pem
            - ${PRIVATE_CERT_FILE_PEM}:/usr/src/app/certs/private-key.pem
            - ${SSL_CA_FILE}:/usr/src/app/certs/ca.pem
        links:
            - mongo_service
            - redis_service
            - ingest
        depends_on:
            - mongo_service
            - redis_service
    mongo_service:
        image: mongo:3.2.0
        volumes:
            - data:/data/db
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
    redis_service:
        image: redis
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "6379:6379"
    ingest:
        image: ingest
        container_name: koala_ingest_${USER}
        extra_hosts:
            - csie.as.northgrum.com:10.8.131.12
        environment:
            - KOALA_ENV
            - KOALA_CONFIG_FILE=/go/config.yml
            - INGEST_PORT
            - LOGNAME
            - KOALA_JIRA_URL
            - KOALA_JIRA_SESSION_URL
            - CERT_FILE_PEM=/go/certs/public.pem
            - PRIVATE_CERT_FILE_PEM=/go/certs/private-key.pem
            - SSL_CA_FILE=/go/certs/ca.pem
            - KOALA_REDIS_URL=redis_service:6379
            - KOALA_MONGO_URL=mongo_service:27017
            - KOALA_USE_CERTS
            - KOALA_MONGO_USERNAME
            - KOALA_MONGO_PASSWORD
            - JIRA_USERNAME=jsikala
            - JIRA_PASSWORD=changeme123
        ports:
            - "${INGEST_PORT}:${INGEST_PORT}"
        volumes:
            - ${CERT_FILE_PEM}:/go/certs/public.pem
            - ${PRIVATE_CERT_FILE_PEM}:/go/certs/private-key.pem
            - ${SSL_CA_FILE}:/go/certs/ca.pem
        links:
            - mongo_service
        depends_on:
            - mongo_service
            - redis_service
```

Essentially the once the docker-compose file is ran then, the app deploys with some data, just like it does on the remote host. Since I can't seem to get the data that's in the remote host export/dumped on to my container, the app doesn't have the data that it needs.

Answer (score 0):

`docker run` is the command you'd use to *start* a mongo container running. You shouldn't need to start running a new container to dump data from an existing container.

If you want to run a command within the container, you'll want to run `docker ps` to find the name of your container & then `docker exec` to run a command within the container (or connect to a shell within the container).

You shouldn't need to connect to the container at all to run `mongoexport` though -- you should be able to just run `mongoexport` with the correct port and creds to dump your data.